# Find $\oint\limits_{|z-\frac{1}{3}|=3} z \text{Im}(z)\text{d}z$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

In my test on complex analysis I encountered following problem:

> Find $\oint\limits_{|z-\frac{1}{3}|=3} z \text{Im}(z)\text{d}z$

So first I observed that function $z\text{Im}(z)$ is not holomorphic at least on real axis. Therefore we have to intgrate using parametrization.

First, let's change variable $w = z - \frac{1}{3}$. So we got $\oint\limits_{|w|=3} (w+\frac{1}{3}) \text{Im}(w+\frac{1}{3})\text{d}w = \oint\limits_{|w|=3} (w+\frac{1}{3}) \text{Im}(w)\text{d}w = \frac{1}{2i}\oint\limits_{|w|=3} (w+\frac{1}{3}) (w-\bar w)\text{d}w$.

Then by letting $w=3e^{i \phi}$ we transform integral to the form 
$\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}(3e^{i \phi}+\frac{1}{3})(3e^{i \phi}-3e^{-i \phi})ie^{i \phi}\text{d}\phi = -\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\text{d}\phi=-\pi$.

Is my reasoning correct? I don't quite sure about change of variable I made since function is not holomorphic at real axis. Is there any other way how this integral can be evaluated? Thanks!

Comment: Reasoning seems okay. You could have made both variable changes at once, but no issue there.  The passage in which you got away with the exponential seems wrong to me though.

Comment: $dw = 3ie^{i\phi}\ d\phi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $\text{Im}(z)=\frac1{2i}(z-\bar z)$, that

$$z\text{Im}(z)=\frac1{2i}(z^2-|z|^2)$$

Since $z^2$ is analytic, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z-\frac13 |=3}z\text{Im}(z)\,dz&=\frac i2\oint_{|z-\frac13 |=3}|z|^2\,dz\\\\
&=-\frac {3}2 \int_0^{2\pi} \left|\frac13 +3e^{i\phi}\right|^2 e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\frac {3}2 \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{10}9 +e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right)e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-3\pi 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Stokes'theorem. Since $z\mathrm{Im}(z)=\frac{1}{2i}(z^2-z\overline{z})$ and $dx\wedge dy=\frac{1}{2i}d\overline{z}\wedge dz$ we have
$$
\oint_{|z-\frac{1}{3}|=3}\frac{z^2-z\overline{z}}{2i}dz=\iint_{|z-\frac{1}{3}|\le3}-z\frac{d\overline{z}\wedge dz}{2i}=\iint_{(x-\frac{1}{3})^2+y^2\le 9}(-x-iy)dx\wedge dy=\\
=-\iint_{(x-\frac{1}{3})^2+y^2\le 9}xdx\wedge dy-i\iint_{(x-\frac{1}{3})^2+y^2\le 9}ydx\wedge dy=\\
=-Average_D(x)\times Volume(D)-iAverage_D(y)\times Volume(D)=\\
=-\frac{1}{3}\times 9\pi-i\cdot 0\times 9\pi=-3\pi
$$
where $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}|(x-\frac{1}{3})^2+y^2\le 9\}$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\oint_{\verts{z - 1/3}\ =\ 3}z\,\Im\pars{z}\,\dd z & =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\pars{{1 \over 3} + 3\expo{\ic\theta}}
\Im\pars{{1 \over 3} + 3\expo{\ic\theta}}3\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
3\ic\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\pars{{1 \over 3}\expo{\ic\theta} + 3\expo{2\ic\theta}}
\bracks{3\sin\pars{\theta}}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
3\ic\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\bracks{\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}\ic + 9\sin\pars{2\theta}\sin\pars{\theta}\ic}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
-6\int_{0}^{\pi}\bracks{{\color{red}{1} -
\cos\pars{2\theta} \over \color{red}{2}} +
9\,{\cos\pars{\theta} - \cos\pars{3\theta} \over 2}}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
-6\int_{0}^{\pi}{1 \over 2}\,\dd\theta = \bbx{-3\pi}
\end{align}